# Function $y=e^{1/\ln(x)}$ has a singularity at $x=1$ which breaks it into two continuous parts. What is the minimum distance between these parts?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The function $y = e^{1/\ln(x)}$ has a singularity at $x = 1$ that partitions it into two separate continuous sections. Notice that it has reflective symmetry about a $y=x$ axis, because it can be re-written as $\ln(x)\ln(y) = 1$.

When plotted, the 'left curve', (i.e. where $x < 1$), has a discreet length, is continuous between the points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0).$

The 'right curve', (i.e. where $x > 1$), is of infinite length. It has asymptotes at $x = 1$, and $y=1$.

I am trying to find the minimum distance between the left and right curves, so slopes must be calculated. The derivative of the function is $$-\frac{y}{x\ln^2(x)}$$
The left curve has a centre point at $(\frac{1}{e}, \frac{1}{e})$, and the tangent at this point is $-1$. The normal there has slope $1$, and intersects the right curve at $(e, e)$.
The tangent at that intersection is also $-1$, so the normal there has a slope of $1$. The straight line between $\left(\frac{1}{e}, \frac{1}{e}\right)$ and $(e, e)$ therefore seems to represent the minimum distance between the left and right curves. It equates to $\sqrt{2}\left(e - \frac{1}{e}\right)$.
But could there be another pair of points, (one in each section) where the distance between them is shorter than this? Clearly they would have to have identical slopes. I think the answer is no but I have not been able to prove it.

It would be nice if a method could be found that could be applied to piecewise-continuous functions in general. Maybe the Lagrangian method could be used, but I've only seen that applied to two distinct functions, and this problem is about a single function that has two separate subdomains.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6):

In fact the distance between the curves is about $4\%$ smaller than $\sqrt{2} \left(e - \frac1e\right)$, small enough that it is not apparent (to me at least) from a plot of the curve.

We can parametrize the right curve by
$${\mathbf r}(s) = \left(\exp s, \exp \frac1s\right) , \quad s > 0.$$

The squared distance $D(s)^2$ between ${\mathbf r}(s)$ and the limit point $(1, 0)$ of the left curve is
$$D(s)^2 = (\exp s - 1)^2 + \left(\exp \frac1s\right)^2 .$$
Differentiating gives that where $D(s)^2$ is minimized, $$\frac{d}{ds}(D(s)^2) = 2 \left(\exp (2 s) - \exp s - \frac{1}{s^2} \exp\frac2s\right) = 0 .$$
This equation has a unique (real) solution, $s_0 \approx 1.07227$ (there doesn't appear to be a nice closed form for $s_0$), and the distance $D(s_0)$ from $(1, 0)$ to ${\bf r}(s_0) \approx {\bf r}(1.07227) \approx (2.92201, 2.54111)$ is $$\approx D(1.07227) \approx 3.18612 < 3.32397\ldots = \sqrt{2} \left(e - \frac1e\right) .$$

[image]

More generally, given two curves $A, B$ (completely) parametrized by ${\bf a}(s)$, $s \in I$, and ${\bf b}(t)$, $t \in J$, respectively, the distance between ${\bf a}(s), {\bf b}(t)$ is $d(s, t) = |{\bf a}(s) - {\bf b}(t)|$, and hence by definition the distance between $A, B$ is
$$\inf_{s \in I, t \in J} d(s, t) .$$ Any local minimum of $d(s, t)$ occurs at a critical point of $d$ hence of $d^2$. At least when $d^2$ is differentiable in $s, t$, finding critical points of $d^2$ amounts to looking for solutions $(s, t)$ to the system $(d^2)_s = (d^2)_t = 0$.

For the curves in the question statement, any choice of point on the left curve can be expressed as ${\bf r}(-t)$, where we now restrict $t$ to $t > 0$. Then, the squared distance between the points ${\bf r}(s), {\bf r}(-t)$ is
$$d(s, t)^2
= \left\vert {\bf r}(s) - {\bf r}(-t)\right\vert^2
= (\exp s - \exp (-t))^2 + \left(\exp \frac1s - \exp \left(-\frac1t\right)\right)^2 .$$

Since replacing $s \mapsto \frac1s$ and $t \mapsto \frac1t$ simply reflects ${\bf r}(s)$ and ${\bf r}(-t)$ about the line $y = x$, about which both curves are symmetric, to search for extrema we may as well restrict our attention to points satisfying $s > t > 0$.

Using a CAS we find that there are $2$ critical points satisfying the above conditions:

- $(s_1, t_1) = (1, 1)$, which corresponds to the pair $(e, e), \left(\frac1e, \frac1e\right)$, separated by a distance $d(1, 1) = \sqrt 2 \left(e 
  - \frac1e\right) \approx 3.32397$.  The determinant of the Hessian is $\det H_{d^2}(1, 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{e^2} > 0$ and $d^2_{ss} = 12 e^2 - 8 > 0$, so $d^2$ has a local minimum at $(1, 1)$, but as observed above, that local minimum is not a global one.
- $(s_2, t_2) \approx (1.03370, 0.48241)$, which corresponds to ${\bf r}(s_2) \approx (0.61730, 0.12581)$ and ${\bf r}(-t_2) \approx (2.81146, 2.63109)$, which are separated by a distance $\approx d(s_2, t_2) \approx 3.33027$. Computing gives $\det H_{d^2}(s_2, t_2) < 0$, hence $(s_2, t_2)$ is a saddle point. (By the symmetry observed above, there is a second saddle point at $(t_2, s_2)$.)

For our curves $D(s_0)$ is smaller than the smallest (in this case, only) local minimum of $d$ and is the distance between the curves.

Comment: This means the shortest distance is not always between common tangent lines?

Comment: No---for example, consider two line segments in general position. In this case, I suspect (but did not show) that $d(t_0)$ is actually the infimum of the distances (I don't think that $d$ attains a minimum, as $(1, 0)$ is only a limit point of the left part of the curve and not a point on the curve itself).

Comment: Using T.W's suggested parameters answers my question about the existence of a method for addressing the problem.

Comment: That answers my question about whether there's a smaller distance than the one I found.  So the shortest distance is from a point a bit to the right of (e, e) and the limit point (1,0). It is interesting that the shortest distance is not on the line of symmetry.

Comment: The use of parameters also addresses my other question, i.e. does a method exist to find shortest distances between different parts of piecewise continuous functions in general.

Comment: @TravisWillse I am not sure if it should be another answer, but minimizing $(e^\frac1{\ln(x)}-e^\frac1{\ln(y)})^2+(x-y)^2$ in this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/3d/9ec8ecdae7), or maybe it can be done parametrically equivalently for $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$,  and using software for the minimum shows you found the global minimum.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I did that (but using nongraph parametrizations), but I couldn't see a clean way to justify manually that the found difference really is the infimum. Still, given the interest in the comment I'll expand it to a proper answer later today, in particular addressing o.p.'s curiosity about a general solution for such problems.

Comment: (@ТymaGaidash Of course, feel free to write up an answer addressing these facts yourself.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out that the general problem of finding the distance between $2$ curves that you can parametrize at least partially amounts to computing the infimum of some $2$-variable function.